# Germany work permit visa denial

Tags: working-visas, germany, refusal

My long term work permit visa got rejected stating that:

> You do not  fulfill the requirement to work as "Leiharbeitnehmer" as intended according to section 2 No.3 of your work contract. Hence, visa can not be issued.

What can be done here to get the visa? What parameter has to be changed or improved to satisfy the visa requirement?

This is the section from my work contract:

> (3) Die Tätigkeit des Arbeitnehmers besteht insbesondere in Einsätzen bei Kunden des Arbeitgebers bezogen auf deren Projekte. Für jeden Einsatz wird der Arbeitnehmer eine gesonderte Einsatzmitteilung erhalten. In dieser wird der jeweilige Dienstsitz bzw. Einsatzort mitgeteilt. Der Arbeitnehmer ist damit einverstanden, für diese Projekte bei den Kunden des Arbeitgebers auch im Rahmen der Arbeitnehmerüberlassung eingesetzt zu werden. In diesem Fall bestimmen sich Rechte und Pflichten des Arbeitsvertrages auch nach den Tarifverträgen, die für allgemein gültig erklärt sind, bzw. die für den Arbeitgeber gelten.

Google translation:

> The activity of the employee consists in particular in employment with clients of the employer related to their projects. For each assignment, the employee will receive a separate notification. In this the respective place of employment or place of employment is communicated. The employee agrees to be used for these projects at the employer's customers as part of temporary employment. In this case, the rights and obligations of the employment contract are also determined by the collective agreements which are declared to be universally valid or which apply to the employer.

Comment: looks like the contract you provide and your qualification in the cv are not matching as much as they want/need....

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I don't see why you're suggesting there's a problem with qualifications or OP's CV, the denial seems to be entirely about contract details.

Answer (score 1):

Section 3 of your work contract states

> Der Arbeitnehmer ist damit einverstanden, für diese Projekte bei den Kunden des Arbeitgebers auch im Rahmen der **Arbeitnehmerüberlassung** eingesetzt zu werden.

This is a typical phrase for e.g. companies doing engineering consulting. You are employed at some *»Super-Consulting GmbH«* and they sell your workforce to *BMW* or some other big company who don't want to hire an extreme specialist just for one project.

The problem with that is there are also a lot of companies in that market who hire cheap laborers e.g. in Bulgaria or Romania (both EU!) and sell their workforce to huge butcheries, construction companies etc. That may be okay too, but there have been numerous cases of trickster companies who rip off both the laborers and the social insurances, leaving those people without a penny and without accomodation in Germany. Often, they can't return to their home country either, which is a huge problem.

That's why this field of *Arbeitnehmerüberlassung* is extremely regulated, especially with non-EU foreigners. (For EU foreigners, the regulations cannot be that tight.)

- The relevant law is [§ 40 Abs. 1 Nr. 2 AufenthG](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthg_2004/__40.html).

In short, you first need a "normal" contract without that phrase for two years or an *EU Blue Card*. Then, this law doesn't apply. There are some other minor loopholes but those two are the main ones.

- [Here's some explanation which may help you finding a loophole.](https://efarbeitsrecht.net/arbeitnehmerueberlassung-mitarbeiter-drittstaaten/)

It's in German. Please discuss it with your future employer.